# Keyboard shortcut for Downloads folder?

Tags: keyboard, finder

I use <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> whenever I go the the Desktop folder. Is it possible to add a shortcut for the Downloads folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> opens the Downloads folder.

Comment: It is, as far as I know. That used to be the key combination for the downloads window in Safari, and it now got moved to Finder. :P

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new service in Automator.
2. Set the dropdowns to Service receives to no input, in any application, or limit it to just the Finder if you like.
3. Add the "Run Shell Script" item, and set the content to `open ~/Downloads`
4. Save the Service, name it whatever you like.
5. In the keyboard shortcuts preference pane, select "Services" from the source list. Find the service you created at the bottom of the list on the right, and give it whatever shortcut you'd like.

Comment: There is no "Downloads" menuitem in the "Go" menu, so I dont think it's possible to create a keybinding via System Preferences.

Comment: @neoneye I've updated this answer to reveal an alternative method that should work for you. Let me know if it works!